# Why do I keep getting error message like 'undefined error'?

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to calculate BMI with the code below, and I kept getting error messages like undefined error and return 1 exit status. I've read somewhere that I need to include a file with .h, so I added `<windows.h>`, but it still doesn't work.

I'm not familiar with classes.

How can I fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class BMI{
public:
    void setWeight (int);
    void setHeight (int);
    int getWeight ();
    int getHeight ();
    int calBMI (int,int);
    void printBMI (int);
    BMI ();
    ~BMI ();
private:
    double weight;
    double height;
    double bmi;
};

int BMI::getWeight(){
    return weight;
}

int BMI::getHeight(){
return height;
}

void BMI::setWeight(int w){
    weight = w;
} 

void BMI::setHeight(int h){
    height = h;
}

int BMI::calBMI(int w, int h){
    return w/(h*h);
}

void BMI::printBMI(int ans){
    cout<<ans<<endl;
}

BMI::BMI(){
    weight = 0;
    height = 0;
}

int main (){
    int w, h, ans;
    BMI body;
    cout<<"\n\tPlease insert your weight = ";
    cin>>w;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"\n\tPlease insert your height = ";
    cin>>h;
    body.setWeight(w); body.setHeight(h);
    ans = body.calBMI(w,h);
    body.printBMI(ans);
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You declared the destructor but never defined it.

Comment: "I kept getting error messages **like** undefined error" How about including the **actual** error?

Comment: Which book are you using to learn the language?

Answer (score 0):

You declared a destructor `~BMI()`, but did not define it. Just remove the declaration. You don't need a destructor. There's nothing to destruct.

There are other problems. Read all warnings and act on them.

Comment: They might not even be warned about.